# I want to save the contacts on screen using shared preference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I wrote code to fetch the contacts from mobile.Now I want to the save contacts to the activity using shared preference.I share my code below.please tell what I have to do? and one more thing is when all contacts get saved to the activity.I want to block the incoming and outgoing calls of contacts which is saved to the activity.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button; 
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BlackListActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "BlackListActivity";
Button add;
ListView lv;
String[] contactList ;
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> blcklist = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> ad;
String spref_identifier = "com.example.app";
String entryIdentifierPrefix = "selectionState_listEntry_";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_black_list);

    add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
    add.setOnClickListener(this);

    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
      while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
          Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
          while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
              list.add(name);
            Log.d(TAG, name);
          }
          pCur.close();
        }
      }

      Collections.sort(list);


    }
    cur.close();

     int x = list.size();
     contactList = new String[x];
     contactList = (String[]) list.toArray(contactList);

     lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

         public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,final int index, long arg3) {

//               Toast.makeText(BlackListActivity.this,lv.getItemAtPosition(index).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             new AlertDialog.Builder(BlackListActivity.this)
             .setMessage("Are you sure want to delete "+lv.getItemAtPosition(index).toString()+" contact number ?")
             .setTitle("Deleting Contact....")
             .setIcon(R.drawable.delete)
             .setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(BlackListActivity.this, lv.getItemAtPosition(index).toString()+" contact number deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                blcklist.remove(index);
                ad.notifyDataSetChanged();
                ad.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }).show();
                    return false;
                }
    }); 

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if( v == add){

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Contact List")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setMultiChoiceItems(contactList, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexSelected, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(isChecked){
            blcklist.add(contactList[indexSelected]);
            list.remove(contactList[indexSelected]);

            }
            else if (!isChecked) {
                blcklist.remove(contactList[indexSelected]);
             }
           }    
        })
        .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(BlackListActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,blcklist);
                lv.setAdapter(ad);
                contactList=(String[]) list.toArray(contactList);
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        }).show();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is the error/non required behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shared preference save data in key-value pair..Its easy to save/fetch small amount of data in share pref but for large data if difficult in your case   if you have many contacts then its difficult to fetch specific contact so its better to store data into database

Comment: will you please tell me how to store into database?

Comment: create database with a table and add contact info in table. check this link http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html